# How to refresh my Jquery function on each page Postback?

Tags: javascript, jquery, refresh

I have created a `JQuery` function. I want to refresh this `JQuery`  on every page load ,page refresh, Postback and Ajax Call. I want to use this file globally so, i don't want call that function on each events of various page control.

How can we refresh this, whenever there is postback or some ajax calls.

```
$jQuery(function () {
        alert("first");
        $jQuery(".rddlInner").each(function () {
            alert("inner");
        });
    });
```

Comment: What exactly you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I have got my answer. The `load` event did the trick.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(window).on("load", function () {
        alert("postback");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

For ajax you can use ajaxComplete event http://api.jquery.com/ajaxcomplete/

```
$( document ).ajaxComplete(function() {
  alert("first");
        $jQuery(".rddlInner").each(function () {
            alert("inner");
        })
});
```